# Google sheet custom formula with SEARCH function using multiple words

Tags: regex, search, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The following formula works to make a search using a custom formula

```
=SEARCH("release",$C:$C))
```

but dont work if I use the logical operator `OR`. Example :

```
=or(SEARCH("release",$C:$C),SEARCH("prod",$C:$C))
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: where is this? conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=(SEARCH("release", $C:$C))+(SEARCH("prod", $C:$C))
```

or:

```
=REGEXMATCH($C:$C, "release|prod")
```

Comment: Many thanks. First trick dont work but the REGEXMATCH very well - `=REGEXMATCH(LOWER($C:$C), "release|prod")`

Comment: I cannot vote to change the score from `zero` to `1` as I get a message that `15 reputations` are needed @player0